# Can i use C# ASP.NET and Node.js for my server logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js

I want to ask if it's possible to use ASP.NET and node.js together for the server side of my app ?

Example: website which is a game and it will have chat before the game starts that will be build on node.js and when the game starts asp.net will be used for the CPU intensive tasks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! The answer to your question is yes. If you want a more specific answer you'll have to ask a more specific question :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you sir. All i need to know was that it's possible to use bought languages so i can make the server side of my app as most optimal as possible. Now that i know it's possible i will just learn it :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can safely transfer all CPU intensive tasks by making asynchronous calls from Node.js to a REST API written in C# or any other multithreaded language which handles CPU heavy processing and use the in built asynchronous feature of Node.js to handle all requests to your gaming app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use both ASP.NET and node , since those 2 are interchable
and resource wize would be a waste.
node could cover all of your needs and putting an IIS especially wiht a scale of several servers would be a waste.
you could use express for the template.